# My python code has stopped detecting keystrokes

Tags: python

It was working before, then I added the enemy rectangle and it has stopped working.

```
import time, copy
import pygame
import random
import os
WINDOW_WIDTH = 560
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 560
WINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT))
red =(255,0,0)
green =(0,255,50)
yellow =(255,255,0)
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
WINDOW.fill(black)
pygame.display.update()
a = 20
b = 20
L = False
R = False
U = False
D = False
##x = [20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200,220,240,260,280,300,320,340,360,380,400,420,440,460,480,500,520]
##ex = x[random.randint(0,24)]
##ey = x[random.randint(0,24)]
player = pygame.Rect(a,b,20,20)
pygame.draw.rect(WINDOW, green, player)
##enemy = pygame.Rect(ex,ey,20,20)
##pygame.draw.rect(WINDOW, red, enemy)
pygame.display.update()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:                  
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:        
                L = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:    
                R = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:       
                U = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:    
                D = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                L = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:     
                R = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:       
                U = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:     
                D = False
        if(D):
            if b < 540:
                pygame.draw.rect(WINDOW, black, player)
                b = b+20
                player = pygame.Rect(a,b,20,20)
                pygame.draw.rect(WINDOW, green, player)
        elif(U):
            if b != 0:
                pygame.draw.rect(WINDOW, black, player)
                b = b-20
                player = pygame.Rect(a,b,20,20)
                pygame.draw.rect(WINDOW, green, player)
        elif(R):
            if a < 540:
                pygame.draw.rect(WINDOW, black, player)
                a = a+20
                player = pygame.Rect(a,b,20,20)
                pygame.draw.rect(WINDOW, green, player)
        elif(L):
            if a != 0:
                pygame.draw.rect(WINDOW, black, player)
                a = a-20
                player = pygame.Rect(a,b,20,20)
                pygame.draw.rect(WINDOW, green, player)
##        time.sleep(0.2)
##        if ex < a:
##            pygame.draw.rect(WINDOW, black, enemy)
##            ex = ex+20
##            enemy = pygame.Rect(ex,ey,20,20)
##            pygame.draw.rect(WINDOW, red, enemy)
##        elif ex > a:
##            pygame.draw.rect(WINDOW, black, enemy)
##            ex = ex-20
##            enemy = pygame.Rect(ex,ey,20,20)
##            pygame.draw.rect(WINDOW, red, enemy)
##        elif ey > b:
##            pygame.draw.rect(WINDOW, black, enemy)
##            ey = ey-20
##            enemy = pygame.Rect(ex,ey,20,20)
##            pygame.draw.rect(WINDOW, red, enemy)
##        elif ey > b:
##            pygame.draw.rect(WINDOW, black, enemy)
##            ey = ey-20
##            enemy = pygame.Rect(ex,ey,20,20)
##            pygame.draw.rect(WINDOW, red, enemy)
##        pygame.display.update()
##        if ex == a and ey == b:
##            WINDOW.fill(white)
##            pygame.display.update()
##            time.sleep(2)
##            os._exit(1)
```

Comment: What did stop working? Your whole game or just the key detection? And all errors you get shouldbe included as well

Comment: How about sharing the code that does work (minus all the commented out cruft) followed by exactly what you added (the diff) that broke it?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Pygame, but I'm pretty sure you're supposed to be updating the display in the main loop, not outside.

`pygame.display.update()` on line 28 should be inside the loop, so under the `while True:` part.

I noticed that you had an update further down, but you commented it out.